# Monitor Windows services with Cygwin

Tags: cygwin

I'm trying to move some of my routine shell operations from PowerShell to Cygwin, mostly as an educational exercise, but also because I'm really beginning to love some of the Linux flavor tools. I'm still trying work out how to list/manipulate Windows services. PowerShell had some very handy tools for this, such as:

```
stop-service [pattern]
start-service [pattern]
gsv (or get-service) [pattern]
```

I work with a lot of custom services lately and would love to not have to switch over to PowerShell to do this in my regular workflow. Has anybody worked this out? Several attempts to google this have been stymied by lots of stuff on how to deal with Cygwin running as a service.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Invoke PowerShell commands from within Cygwin:

```
cmd /c '%SystemRoot%\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe' -Command "gsv"
```

And a more general solution would be to create a script `powershell.sh` which contains:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
set -u
cmd /c '%SystemRoot%\\system32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe' -Command "$@"
```

After which you can run: `./powershell.sh gsv` or whatever commands you need.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks!  I've been adding lots of this kind of stuff to the .bashrc file.  I'm guessing the advantage of the .sh file is just to help keep stuff organized?

Comment: To keep it organized, and also makes it easier to share (in my case it's in our source repository)

Answer (score 0):

Invoke PowerShell from within Cygwin without calling CMD.exe.

With PowerShell 6.x Core's `pwsh` command we finally have powershell as another tool in our scripting chest along side perl, ruby, python, etc.

Current versions of powershell can be used as a shebang without issues   ```#!pwsh`.  Older Win7 version of PS2 was tied to the DOS console in such a way that you had to make a wrapper and call that wrapper in the she-bang line.